# Erlang Dynamic Record Editing

Tags: dynamic, erlang, record

I'm storing some data in `mnesia`, and I'd like to be able to change most of the values involved.

The naive

```
change(RecordId, Slot, NewValue) ->
    [Rec] = do(qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(rec), X#rec.id =:= RecordId])),
    NewRec = Rec#rec{Slot=NewValue},
    F = fun() -> mnesia:write(NewRec) end,
    {atomic, Val} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    Val.
```

doesn't do it; the compiler complains that `Slot` is not an `atom` or `_`. Is there a way to express a general slot editing function as above, or am I going to be stuck defining a whole bunch of `change_slot`s?

A marginally better approach is to pull out the `insert` and `find` pieces

```
atomic_insert(Rec) ->
    F = fun() -> mnesia:write(Rec) end,
    {atomic, Val} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    Val.

find(RecordId) -> 
    [Rec] = do(qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(rec), X#rec.id =:= RecordId])),
    Rec.

change(RecordId, name, NewValue) ->
    Rec = find(RecordId),
    NewRec = Rec#rec{name=NewValue},
    atomic_insert(NewRec);
change(RecordId, some_other_property, NewValue) ->
    Rec = find(RecordId),
    NewRec = Rec#rec{some_other_property=NewValue},
    ...
```

but there's still a bit of code duplication there. Is there any way to abstract that pattern out? Is there an established technique to allow records to be edited? Any ideas in general?

Comment: See section 9.8, "Internal Representation of Records", in http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html. The field names are only available at compile time, so you can't use a variable for the field name in the #rec syntax. The record_info() function might be of help for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of using that a record is really a tuple would be:

```
change(RecordId, Index, NewValue) ->
    [Rec] = do(qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(rec), X#rec.id =:= RecordId])),
    NewRec = setelement(Index, Rec, NewValue),
    F = fun() -> mnesia:write(NewRec) end,
    {atomic, Val} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    Val.
```

which you could use like this:

```
5> Val = record:change(id58, #rec.name, new_value).
```

This is also a "clean" use of records as tuples as you are using the `#rec.name` syntax to find the index of the field in the tuple. It was the reason this syntax was added.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. As a note to people reading the question, [`element/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#element-2) was also useful here.

Answer (score 4):

Since records are represented by tuples, you could try using tuple operations to set individual values.

```
-module(rec).
-export([field_num/1, make_rec/0, set_field/3]).
-record(rec, {slot1, slot2, slot3}).

make_rec() ->
  #rec{slot1=1, slot2=2, slot3=3}.

field_num(Field) ->
  Fields = record_info(fields, rec),
  DifField = fun (FieldName) -> Field /= FieldName end,
  case length(lists:takewhile(DifField, Fields)) of
    Length when Length =:= length(Fields) ->
      {error, not_found};
    Length ->
      Length + 2
  end.

set_field(Field, Value, Record) ->
  setelement(field_num(Field), Record, Value).
```

set_field will return an updated record:

```
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c(rec).
{ok,rec}
2> A = rec:make_rec().
{rec,1,2,3}
3> B = rec:set_field(slot3, other_value, A).
{rec,1,2,other_value}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also define `change` as a macro (especially if it used only inside the module):

```
-define(change(RecordId, Slot, NewValue),
        begin
            [Rec] = do(qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(rec), X#rec.id =:= RecordId])),
            NewRec = Rec#rec{Slot=NewValue},
            F = fun() -> mnesia:write(NewRec) end,
            {atomic, Val} = mnesia:transaction(F),
            Val
        end).
```

Usage:

```
test(R, Id) ->
    ?change(Id, name, 5).
```

With macro you can also pass `_` as a field (good for pattern matching).